# Implementing URL shortening with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a URL shortening service with Cassandra. I have:

- 3 cassandra nodes (on Docker)
- function which encodes a base10 to a base62 number (string)

For example:

```
1 => a, 2 => b, 1205 => JR
```

Problem with this approach is that I need to be **sure** to always give a unique (incremented number) so that the next function call will give me a unique string back.

```
CREATE TABLE urls (
  id int PRIMARY KEY, // 1215 (auto increment)
  short_key text, // calculated short string from 1215
  url text, // real url
  created_at timestamp
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC);
```

With a `DESC clustering`, I can always get a last id from the row. This creates few problems:

1. Reading a row before every write
2. If you have a lot of writes, all
   servers must know the next number, which is **slow**

How would you solve this problem? I've tried googling for a solution but in every solution I've found a bottleneck. Also, hashing is not an option.

Comment: Did you try to use "counters" which are built for this very purpose?

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html

Comment: As @xmas79 stated, you can't update and read counter values at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which performance is OK for you, but I could suggest the following solution based on Cassandra:

You can keep separate counter per user server. Each server is assigned a unique id from 1 to 62 (I suppose that 62 servers will be enough in your case). The id is stored somewhere in server config. You create a counter table:

```
CREATE TABLE uniquecnt (
serverid int PRIMARY KEY,
cnt counter
) PRIMARY KEY (serverid)
```

when server is started it reads counter value by its own id and increments it in memory each time new id is requested. Also it is necessary to increment counter in Cassandra. If update to Cassandra passes without exception the value can be used for URL generation. (Also use at least Quorum consistency level when updating Cassandra.)

For url generation you have to use a kind of concatenation of
domain +"/" + base62(serverId) + base62(counterValue)

In this case you will have your url a bit longer (for 1 letter), but the problem solved.

Here I assume that you are able to keep counter state in memory of each server between transactions. Also you should not update counter in parallel in the scope of one server.

(In general you don't even have to use counter type of table. It will work with simple one also.)

Comment: BTW There is also optimization possible. On each server you can update Cassandra counter ahead for 10 numbers:
UPDATE uniquecnt  SET cnt = cnt + 10  WHERE serverid=55;

As soon as you use these 10 numbers for URLs you repeat the operation. By this you will get 10 times less writes to Cassandra. But in this case you anyway have to separately record all URLs you've given to the user somewhere else in Cassandra. In case you server crashes you will need to skip all those you given to the user. This is a bit more complicated in implementation, but doable.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to deal with a *distributed counter*. As you just found, they are hard, and C* won't solve that problem either, even using its version of [counters](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html) because you can't update **and** read at the same time the counter values.

I'm not an expert, but I'd suggest you to look on some queuing system, like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) just to name a few.